# Disqus in MediaWiki

Tags: facebook, mediawiki, disqus

I used to have the [Facebook Comments extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FacebookComments) on my wiki but it didn't work very well and I couldn't moderate it so yesterday I switched to [disqus](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AvbDisqus). With Disqus, I need to add  tags to every page, while the FB comments were added automatically everywhere.

How do I make the disqus render on every page like the FB plugin did?

Comment: Did you see this [Disqus extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageDisqus)? It adds the Disqus comment box to every page.

Answer (score 1):

The alien's reply worked: Did you see this [Disqus extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageDisqus)? It adds the Disqus comment box to every page.